# How do I RDP into an Azure windows VMSS

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, rdp, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VMSS which is not connected to a load balancer running windows 2016 server edition operating system. How can I RDP into this setup? Is port 3389 open by default?

Comment: where is VMSS' image come from? from Azure or upload from local?

Comment: Create a stand-alone VM on the VNet running you VMSS, allow RDP to the stand-alone VM from your location and then you can RDP into the appropriate VMSS host from the stand-alone VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Azure image to create VMSS, you can **create a windows VM work as a jumpbox** in that same Vnet.

If you use image which upload from your local, **please make sure you have enable RDP first**, then you can use another VM to RDP it via internal IP address.

If you image does not enable RDP, please re-prepare your image and enable RDP, then upload to Azure to create a new VMSS.

Comment: thank you this helped. I made a new image with RDP enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to go to your vnet, search for your vm scale set and you should be able to see the IP.

Comment: By FAAAAR the easiest solution!